# How to use 3 radio button and relate those button to different styling for div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a div tag and wrote some content in it. and have created 3 types of styling effect for that div tag. so have created 3 radio buttons and now i dont know how to connect these things together. If check one of the radio button the div tag should take one of the styling.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide some code on what you already tried yourself

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how you can improve your question to get better response. Creating a jsfiddle will go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with css only.

```css
input[value="blue"]:checked ~ div {
  background: blue;
}
input[value="yellow"]:checked ~ div {
  background: yellow;
}
input[value="orange"]:checked ~ div {
  background: orange;
}
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<label for="blue">blue</label>
<input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="group1">
<label for="yellow">yellow</label>
<input type="radio" value="yellow" id="yellow" name="group1">
<label for="orange">orange</label>
<input type="radio" value="orange" id="orange" name="group1">
<div></div>
```